# How to add URL's to wiki (MediaWiki) powered documentation?

Tags: virtualization, url, mediawiki, wiki

We have an internal company wiki. The wiki engine being used is [MediaWiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MediaWiki), the wiki engine that runs Wikipedia. Some of it contains IT stuff.

One of the things i want want to have are hyperlinks to the various virtual machines. An example of a command, as it needs to run, is:

```
vmrc://solo.avatopia.com:5901/Windows 2000 Server
```

My first thought was to convert the URL into a link:

```
[vmrc://solo.avatopia.com:5901/Windows 2000 Server]
```

But the content renders literally as above: with the square brackets and all. Testing with other URL protocols:

```
[http://solo.avatopia.com]
[ftp://solo.avatopia.com]
[ldap://solo.avatopia.com]
[vmrc://solo.avatopia.com]
```

Only the first two work, and are converted to hyperlinks. The other two remain as liternal text. How can i add URLs to MediaWiki powered documentation?

---

**Original Question**

We have an internal company wiki. The wiki engine being used is [MediaWiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MediaWiki), the wiki engine that runs Wikipedia. Some of it contains IT stuff.

One of the things i want want to have are hyperlinks to the various virtual machines. An example of a command, as it needs to run, is:

```
\\solo\VMRC Client\vmrc.exe solo.avatopia.com:5901/Windows 2000 Server
```

If launching from a command prompt, you have to quote the spaces:

```
C:\>"\\solo\VMRC Client\vmrc.exe" solo.avatopia.com:5901/"Windows 2000 Server"
```

My first thought in converting the above for use on our wiki-site, is to simply HTML-ify it:

```
file://\\solo\VMRC Client\vmrc.exe solo.avatopia.com:5901/&quot;Windows 2000 Server&quot;
```

but MediaWiki only converts **file://\solo\VMRC** to a hyperlink, the remainder is text.

i've tried other random things, including enclosing the URL in square brackets.

What is the correct answer? i don't want to happen to randomly stumble on some format that *happens* to work today, and breaks in the future.

Comment: What is the wiki software?  The software in use determines the text syntax.

Comment: Sorry. Wikipedia. i thought wiki was synonymous with wikipedia's software. i can't really say "wikipedia", becuse that is the de-facto web-site that uses wiki software.

Comment: i guess the proper name of the software is "WikiMedia" - what wikipedia uses.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The protocols (http, ftp, gopher, etc) which turn into links when surrounded by square brackets ([]) are defined in the $wgUrlProtocols array in your LocalSettings.php file. Here are the default protocols allowed.

```
$wgUrlProtocols = array(
    'http://',
    'https://',
    'ftp://',
    'irc://',
    'gopher://',
    'telnet://', // Well if we're going to support the above.. -ævar
    'nntp://', // @bug 3808 RFC 1738
    'worldwind://',
    'mailto:',
    'news:'
);
```

To fix your problem, add vmrc as a protocol. Add/replace the following in your LocalSettings.php file:

```
$wgUrlProtocols = array(
    'http://',
    'https://',
    'ftp://',
    'irc://',
    'gopher://',
    'telnet://', // Well if we're going to support the above.. -ævar
    'nntp://', // @bug 3808 RFC 1738
    'worldwind://',
    'mailto:',
    'news:',
    'vmrc://',
);
```

You can now create links using the square bracket syntax: (The URL comes first, separated from the link text by one space. Spaces are not allowed in the URL.)
    [vmrc://solo.avatopia.com:5901 Windows 2000 Server]

Comment: A more portable way could be: `$wgUrlProtocols[] = 'vmrc://';` which just "extends" the existing array.

Comment: adding to David's reply, you need to escape the blanks with %20

Answer (score 0):

I use pmwiki, they have a command so that when you encapsulate the text with [@   @] that it is printed as quoted and not changed into the wiki code - does that work for MediaWiki?

Comment: It does not work on MediaWiki, but i want to be clear. Does that turn your text into a hyperlink? Or does it output the text as is, but is not a link?  When i try it, i literally get the square brackets and the @ signs.

Comment: @ddrager In MediaWiki, use the <nowiki></nowiki> tags to keep MediaWiki from parsing the text.

Answer (score 0):

URLs are for pointing to resources not commands to be run.

You can link to a batch script (as mentioned above), or you can display the text in `monospace, code form` and let users copy & paste.

Answer (score 0):

Sample to add url in mediawiki

```
[http://www.example.com/ Example Site] --> Output will be 'Example Site'
http://www.example.com --> output will be 'http://www.example.com'
```